# Eclipse Luna Dark Theme Modification: Change //Comments to be more distinct

Tags: eclipse, themes

Is there a way to modify this theme, which is pretty great, to make the comments more distinct? The light grey default is quite hard to read when my screen backlight is low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring.

Expand the 'Comments' sections. Selecting the comment type (Multi-line, single-line) will enable the color box on the right hand side. Pick away!

Comment: Thank you sooo much! You are my eye saver!